# How to declare two different type variables through argpars

Tags: python, argparse

Argps approach need to accept two different types of variables, in this case only the array of string is accepting values and the int variable do not. how do i solve this? or is this the best approach to the case? I´m very new whit python thanks to all

python code:

```
def read_cmdline_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-l", "--search_by_name", help="Search by name", 
     type=str, nargs='+')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args

cmdline_args = read_cmdline_args()
uSerach_by_name = cmdline_args.serach_by_name

session.serach_by_name(tags=uSerach_by_name, amount=uSerach_by_name)
```

Original method:

```
session.serach_by_name(["peter"], amount=2)
```

command line:

```
py quickstart.py --l peter john 2 (the value 2 which is amount is not being accepted )
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to pass list of words and some number? Simply add another argument:

```
def read_cmdline_args():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-s", "--search_by_name", type=str, nargs='+', help="Search by name")

    # added argument
    parser.add_argument("-a", "--amount", type=int, default=0, help="Some amount")

    return parser.parse_args()
```

Now you can run the script like this:

```
py quickstart.py -s peter john -a 2
```

Parsed arguments are:

```
Namespace(amount=2, search_by_name=['peter', 'john'])
```